# If Men in Black don't exist how do they have homes?

Tags: men-in-black

Officially the Men in Black agents do not exist. No paper trail or forensics of them can be found. So one has to ask how does J and likely every other agent have a home to live in when not on shift?

Comment: Because MIB own the properties they live in.

Comment: Wipe the memory of the landlord as soon as you have the rental agreement signed ? Oh wait, why even the agreement, swipe memory, occupy and enjoy !

Comment: How hard can it be for MIB to arrange for the agents to rent or buy housing under false identities?   And as some have suggested, possibly MIB owns an apartment building and/or a neighborhood of houses for agents to live in.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although it's not *confirmed* in the films (or their accompanying novels), the reality seems to be that MIB probably own and operate the apartments that their Agents live in.

> **Z:** *[You](https://youtu.be/Wmrwj6DDt-4?t=26) will conform to the identity we give you, eat where we tell you, **live where we tell you***

The most obvious evidence for this is the large armoury found in Agent K's old apartment. It seems very unlikely that K would have had the personal skills to install **and equip** such a large add-on without at least *consulting* with his superiors.

[image]

J's apartment (from MIB:3) seems spartan to the extreme. Basically just somewhere to sleep and chill before returning to work in 8 hours. Note that it's also in the standard MIB monochrome colour-scheme.

[image]

Comment: It's more or less hinted at in the 'welcome speech' by Z: "You'll conform to the identity we give you, eat where we tell you, live where we tell you." While they have their agent identity, they're human, they need to unwind and such, they can't be on-call 24/7 in the MIB compound, that's recipe to go crazy which would be bad with the tech they have at hand.

Comment: That's 36/4.6667, not 24/7, in Centurion days. You either get used to it or go mad.

Comment: Haha... I'd never noticed the picture (or maybe it's a (possibly chalk/charcoal) painting) of Frank before :)

Comment: Isn't though in the second movie, they go back to K's old apartment which is occupied by civilians at the time to retrieve some items and then mind wipe on the way out?

Comment: @BPugh - Yes, presumably MiB are letting the apartment out (in the absence of an Agent to occupy it).

Comment: "Thats hot, yeah that's hot" - Agent J witnessing alien activity

Comment: Intergalactic keggers can become quite expensive. It's on AirBnB for sure.